# Multiple Selection with ListView in android

Tags: android

I am developing an app.In which i have a list of message, this list of particular row contain sender name, msg title with a checkbox.when selecting these multiple cheakbox getting valur from particular row and on click of delete image button all messages should be deleted..I am trying but getting failed...plz help me..

**Code:**

```
btmsgdelete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
                StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
                System.out.println("within deletion of message");
                for(Message msg:almsg)
                {
                    if(msg.isSelected()) 
                    {
                        sb.append(msg.getEmpid()+msg.getHeader());
                        sb.append(",");
                        if(sb!=null)
                        {
                            System.out.println("Length of stringbuffer is :"+sb.length());
                            for (int i = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) 
                            {
                                System.out.println(i);
                            }
                        }

                        int idx=sb.lastIndexOf(",");
                        System.out.println("idx"+idx);
                        if(idx>0)
                        {
                            sid = sb.substring(0, idx) + sb.substring(idx+1);

                        }

                        lvmessagelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View arg1, int arg2, long arg3)
                            {

                                CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

                                Message msg=almsg.get(position);

                                if (msg.isSelected()) 
                                {
                                    msg.setSelected(false);
                                    chk.setChecked(false);
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                                    msg.setSelected(true);
                                    chk.setChecked(true);
                                }
                                System.out.println("msg is selected");
                                 msgid=almsg.get(position).getEmpid();
                                System.out.println(msgid);
                                 empname=almsg.get(position).getEmpname();
                                System.out.println(empname);
                                 msgheader=almsg.get(position).getHeader();
                                System.out.println(msgheader);


                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Context is not clear buddy. add some more intel.

Comment: you want to delete the selected item. right?...

Comment: yes right Ram...exactly i want this..

Answer (score 0):

For deleting the selected list item on Imagebutton click event by

```
       ImageButton deleteButton = (ImageButton) row.findViewById(R.id.imagebutton);

        deleteButton.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    SparseBooleanArray positions = getListView().getCheckedItemPositions();
                    int itemCount = getListView().getCount();
                    for(int i=0;i<itemCount;i++){
                     getListView().remove(i);
                     notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }

                }
            }
        );
```

You can get the check box value by

```
  Message msg=almsg.get(position);
```

and store it in a global array for your reference.

Comment: @user2837556 You can give your listview object instead of getListView().